# Fail to do apt-get update on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, apt

I recieve this error all the time when I try to do **apt-get update** so that can not install or remove software with apt

```
Get:102 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en                                            
100% [102 Translation-en bzip2 0 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com]                                    7273 B/s 0sbzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
100% [98 Translation-en gzip 0 B] [Waiting for headers]                                                   7273 B/s 0sE: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en.decomp (1)
100% [99 Translation-en gzip 0 B] [Waiting for headers]                                                  14.9 kB/s 0sE: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en.decomp (1)
Fetched 6406 kB in 57s (111 kB/s)  
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en.decomp (1)
100% [99 Translation-en gzip 0 B] [Waiting for headers]                                                  14.9 kB/s 0sE: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en.decomp (1)
Fetched 6406 kB in 57s (111 kB/s)                                                                                    
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en  

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en  

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_universe_i18n_Translation-en  Encountered a section with no Package: header

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I think the reason is this error

```
100% [98 Translation-en gzip 0 B] [Waiting for headers]                                                  7273 B/s 0s
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en.decomp (1)
100% [99 Translation-en gzip 0 B] [Waiting for headers]                                                14.9 kB/s 0s
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en.decomp (1)
```

I already try as **root**

```
apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
mv lists lists.old
mkdir -p lists/partial
apt-get clean
apt-get update
exit
```

and the same problem, remove entire **/var/lib/apt** then run **apt-get update** also the same problem.
This is my first time, I think that the problem may relate to internet connection? Is that possible?

UPDATE: my /etc/apt/sourced.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
```

Comment: Hi, could you please copy/past your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file?

Comment: Hi, I add it as update in my question!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today, I fixed it by remove all the apt lists and running apt-get update again.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried! but it not work, same problem like I describe